# Transfer my m.website to my responsive website without losing my SE ranking

Tags: seo, search-results, transfer

Until last month I was using two versions of my website: one for desktop and one for mobile. (`m.example.com` / `example.com`)  A few weeks ago I made my desktop version responsive.

In order to redirect my search engine traffic, I simply added a *.htaccess* on my mobile version which redirects `m.example.com/path` to`example.com/path`. I also let the headers links `rel="canonical"` and `rel="alternate"` on both versions.

After a few weeks, my m.website is still showing up in the search results and the traffic is still counted in my m.website Google Search Console.

I would like to know what are the next steps to definitely tell google than my website has moved to a responsive design **without losing my ranking**.

Comment: It isn't possible to use both redirects and `rel=canonical` at the same time.   The canonical link tag goes in the HTML source.   If you redirect, nobody sees that source.

Comment: The reason I let `rel="canonial` on m.example.com and `rel="alternate"` on example.com is because I red that I could get penalise for duplicate content

Comment: But you also say you put in redirects.   Those two are not compatible.   Can you give a link to your site so we can look to see what is actually going on?

Comment: yes, should I just remove `rel="cononical"` and `rel="alternate"` then ? I'm afraid to lose ranking.

Comment: If the redirect is working, you should remove them.

Comment: ok, i removed `rel="cononical"` on m.example.com and `rel="alternate"` example.com. I'll see how it goes. If you can Answer my thread, i'll tick it green.

Comment: I haven't really answered your question.   I'm still confused about how you think you have both rel canonical and redirects at the same time.   There is something wrong.

Comment: when I had both versions, I had rel canonical. Then I made my responsive design and I just added a 301 redirects to my mobile version which redirect to my desktop responsive version without removing my rel canonical. Make sense?

Comment: That does not make sense.  If you put redirects in place it takes down the mobile website including any tags in the pages.

Comment: ok, however the m.example is still showing up in the SERP. User click then get redirected to the responsive website.

Comment: Google usually fixes that within a couple weeks.  You say that it has been several weeks.   That seem pretty slow.   I'd check to see if your redirects are properly implemented.

Comment: All my redirects works fine. I now deleted my `rel="cononical"` and `rel="alternate" `. Do you think I should put it back in order to not get penalised for duplicate content or other things?

Comment: If your redirects are working, your rel meta tags aren't doing anything.

Comment: This can take a while depending upon how Google sees your site (popular, fresh, trendy, etc.). It can take weeks or even months. Often months. A few weeks is likely not enough time.